# Как заставить HttpClient использовать socks5 c#

Tags: c#

Как заставить HttpClient использовать socks5 прокси?
Я нашел одно решение:

```
var socksProxy = new Socks5ProxyClient(Proxy.Split(':')[0], Convert.ToInt32(Proxy.Split(':')[1]));
var handler = new ProxyHandler(socksProxy);
handler.UseCookies = true;
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var request = new HttpClient(handler))
```

сокс5 прокси работает, но почему то при отправке пост запроса не отправляется Content-Length и тем самым сервер не отдает куки, зато без прокси все нормально работает, Content-Length отправляется